# Agregar funcion en un evento con javascript

Tags: javascript

hice pruebas con este codigo creandolo como funcion y agregandolo a un envetListener tomando los datos de un input, pero no logre hacerlo funcionar.

Asi como expongo el codigo funciona bien. Mi problema esta a la hora de aplicarlo en un eventListener lograr que funcione.

Espero se entienda mi consulta. Gracias

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Descuentos</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>descuentos en tu compra
    </h1>
    <ul>
        <li>comprando mas de 100 pesos tenes un 5% de descuento</li>
        <li>comprando mas de 500 pesos tenes un 15% de descuento</li>
        <li>comprando mas de 1500 pesos tenes un 30% de descuento</li>
    </ul>


    <p id="respuesta"></p>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
const respuesta = document.getElementById('respuesta');
let descuento;
let compra;

compra = 1560; // dependiendo de este valor va a variar la respuesta

if (compra > 100 && compra <= 500 ) {
        descuento = compra - ( compra * 0.05 );
        respuesta.style.display = "block";
        respuesta.innerText = `Hiciste una compra de $${compra}. Tenes un descuento del 5% y el total es $${descuento}`;
    } else if ( compra > 500 && compra <= 1500 ) {
        descuento = compra - ( compra * 0.15 );
        respuesta.style.display = "block";
        respuesta.innerText = `Hiciste una compra de $${compra}. Tenes un descuento del 15% y el total es $${descuento}`;
    } else if ( compra > 1500 ) {
        descuento = compra - ( compra * 0.3 );
        respuesta.style.display = "block";
        respuesta.innerText = `Hiciste una compra de $${compra}. Tenes un descuento del 30% y el total es $${descuento}`;
    } else {
        respuesta.style.display = "block";
        respuesta.innerText = `Comprasete $${compra}. No tenes ningun descuento que aplicar.`;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola para el siguiente código utilicé `jquery`.
Si no quieres utilizar `jquery` te dejaré comentado la parte del código sin `jquery`.

Agregué un `input` donde guardo el valor de la compra y un `button` al que le añado el `listener`.

```js
$("#compra").on('click',compra);
//document.getElementById('compra').addEventListener("click",compra);

//Creo la función compra y dentro coloco tu código
function compra(){

    const respuesta = document.getElementById('respuesta');
    let descuento;
    let compra;
    /** se obtiene el valor del input agregado, si lo creas de tipo
    * texto tendrás que validar que lo que tenga como valor sea una 
    * serie de números y castearlo como un valor numérico
    */
    compra = $('#pesos').val();
    //compra = document.getElementById('pesos').value;

    if (compra > 100 && compra <= 500 ) {
        descuento = compra - ( compra * 0.05 );
        respuesta.style.display = "block";
        respuesta.innerText = `Hiciste una compra de $${compra}. Tenes un descuento del 5% y el total es $${descuento}`;
    } else if ( compra > 500 && compra <= 1500 ) {
        descuento = compra - ( compra * 0.15 );
        respuesta.style.display = "block";
        respuesta.innerText = `Hiciste una compra de $${compra}. Tenes un descuento del 15% y el total es $${descuento}`;
    } else if ( compra > 1500 ) {
        descuento = compra - ( compra * 0.3 );
        respuesta.style.display = "block";
        respuesta.innerText = `Hiciste una compra de $${compra}. Tenes un descuento del 30% y el total es $${descuento}`;
    } else {
        respuesta.style.display = "block";
        respuesta.innerText = `Comprasete $${compra}. No tenes ningun descuento que aplicar.`;
    }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Descuentos</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>descuentos en tu compra
    </h1>
    <ul>
        <li>comprando mas de 100 pesos tenes un 5% de descuento</li>
        <li>comprando mas de 500 pesos tenes un 15% de descuento</li>
        <li>comprando mas de 1500 pesos tenes un 30% de descuento</li>
    </ul>
    <!--botón al que se le agrega el event listener-->
    <button id="compra" >compra</button>
    <!--agruegué un input donde se captura la venta-->
    <input id="pesos" type="number">
    <p id="respuesta"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Que tal Alejandroo00, seria bueno dar contexto de tu respuesta, como solucionaste el problema, o que cambios tiene que hacer Juan para poder llegar a tu resultado. Esto ayudará muchísimo a cualquier persona que precise de replicar la pregunta y/o la respuesta.

Comment: @VíctorHugoTirado, creí haber dejado los comentarios, parece que solo quedó uno, gracias por la observación

Comment: Muchas gracias @alejandro00 !!! me sirvio!!!